# Weird behavior when accessing matrix during loop

Tags: matlab

I want to turn some code into a loop, but the results are correct.

This is the original code.

`f` is just a column matrix of some coefficients that I'm indexing into.

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;

a1 = f(1) * sin(x);
a2 = a1 + f(2) * sin(3*x);
a3 = a2 + f(3) * sin(5*x);
a4 = a3 + f(4) * sin(7*x);
a5 = a4 + f(5) * sin(9*x);
a6 = a5 + f(6) * sin(11*x);
a7 = a6 + f(7) * sin(13*x);
a8 = a7 + f(8) * sin(15*x);
a9 = a8 + f(9) * sin(17*x);
a10 = a9 + f(10) * sin(19*x);
```

I have the following code, but it is not producing the same results.

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
a = [f(1) * sin(x)];
for n = 2:10
    a = [a; a(n-1) + f(n) * sin((2*n-1) * x)];
end
```

I have a suspicion that the indexing into the array while I'm creating a new one is causing issues, but I'm not completely sure.

Any tips for debugging this mess would be great.

Comment: Does referencing it as `a(n-1,:)` fix your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `a = [a; a(n-1) + f(n) * sin((2*n-1) * x)];` and `a(n-1)` only takes one value from a than a row. Therefore, the fix is replacing `a(n-1)` with `a(n-1,:)`.

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
a = [f(1) * sin(x)];
for n = 2:10
    a = [a; a(n-1,:) + f(n) * sin((2*n-1) * x)];
end
```

yields

```
0.00    0.03    0.06    0.09    0.13    0.16    0.19 ....
0.00    0.22    0.44    0.65    0.86    1.06    1.26 ....
0.00    0.69    1.36    2.01    2.62    3.19    3.69 ....
0.00    1.56    3.07    4.47    5.71    6.75    7.56 ....
0.00    2.96    5.75    8.22    10.23   11.69   12.52 ....
0.00    4.99    9.57    13.38   16.12   17.61   17.78 ....
0.00    7.77    14.67   19.97   23.11   23.85   22.24 ....
0.00    11.40   21.15   27.87   30.72   29.51   24.71 ....
0.00    15.98   29.03   36.86   38.32   33.59   24.15 ....
0.00    21.60   38.33   46.62   45.16   35.16   19.89 ....
```